# Linq query assigning count= zero to list object in mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

My code:

```
List <bu_businesslayer> bus = ab.classid(UserAccess).Where(x => x.UserAccess == UserAccess).ToList();
return View(bus);
```

Now `ab` has `count = 202`, but doesn't get assigned to bus. Bus has count = 0. I don't know why. I appreciate if you help.

bu_businesslayer is class file present in class library.

Comment: `var count = ab.classid(UserAccess).Count()` what is the value of `count` in your case ?

Comment: Hi koryakinp, count is 202.

Comment: What is UserAccess ? and what does classid  method do ?

Comment: UserAccess is the username of account holder. classid method will make connection with database and retrieve data to be displayed in the view.

Comment: Maybe, the `Where` condition has not been met, and it returns 0 items.

Comment: You are missing some crtitical information in above code. The type and value of `UserAccess` variable needs to be included in above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where() does not affect ab, it's copy ab and returning result, so you can check where your collection count = 0;

Check the results of `ab.classid(UserAccess).ToList()` what count of result? Is count of it equal 0?

If not, the purpose in `Where` expression. How many objects in `ab` satisfy the condition `x => x.UserAccess == UserAccess` after first operation? And what is UserAccess? If it `class`, so you should learn more about [object equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping me out. I realized where I was going wrong and now I am able to solve my problem. I was filtering out the data twice which apparently did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try initilizing the bus first using
   List <bu_businesslayer> bus=new List <bu_businesslayer>();
      and then,
       bus = ab.classid(UserAccess).Where(x => x.UserAccess == 
     UserAccess).ToList();
     and see the relults.
```

if this also doesnot work the where condition is not met.